# Ext.js confirm method add new line character

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a problem about **Ext.MessageBox.confirm** method. I want to add a new line to confirm message but if i put **\n** it is not work, if i put html new line **br** 
it works but **br** is shown in message. My methot is shown below. br is inside <>

```
confirm: function(message, callback) {
    this.localizeExtMessageBox();
    Ext.MessageBox.confirm(this.getLocalizedString(Ab.view.View.z_MESSAGE_CONFIRM), message, callback);
}
```

How can i do that, thank you.

Comment: Thank you i found solution, if i write [br] it works.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
 Ext.MessageBox.show({
         title: 'my title',
         icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
         msg: 'text here</br> other text in new line?',
         buttonText: { yes: "Yes", no: "No" },
         fn: function (btn) {
           if (btn == 'yes') {
            //your realization
           }
         }
       }
     });
```

Comment: Akthough this works, I feel this is NOT xhtml compliant. It should be <br/> instead. Or am I missing stuff?